# Idiomatic way to run test-suites in stack

Tags: haskell, testing, haskell-stack

Haskell beginner here.

I am struggling to find a nice way to run my test-suites that I have defined in my `.cabal` file. Given that you add `test-suite` sections in the `.cabal` file I would expect that you can run all of them with a single command like `stack runtests`.

The best answer I found is this one:
[Haskell Stack Ghci test-suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558002/haskell-stack-ghci-test-suite) suggesting that you have to run

`stack ghci --test module:test:libtests`

However, there are two things that irritate me and I think that there must be a better way doing it.

1. It is cumbersome to call `stack ghci --test module:test:libtests` explicitly. I don't want to do that if I have more test-suites when projects get larger.
2. Even worse, I end up in an interactive session and have to call `main` myself. This does not scale.

Isn't there a better way to run your test-suites for a project in stack? Of course I could do some shell scripting, but hey stack should *know* how to run my tests, I specified everything in the `.cabal` file.

I tried `stack runghc --test` but that doesn't help.

Project setup:

```
.
├── app
│   └── Main.hs
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── Setup.hs
├── src
│   ├── Lib.hs
│   └── WordNumber.hs
├── stack.yaml
├── test
│   └── Spec.hs
└── WordNumber.cabal
```

`WordNumber.cabal`

```
name:                WordNumber
version:             0.1.0.0
-- synopsis:
-- description:
homepage:            https://github.com/githubuser/WordNumber#readme
license:             BSD3
license-file:        LICENSE
author:              Author name here
maintainer:          example@example.com
copyright:           2017 Author name here
category:            Web
build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  README.md
cabal-version:       >=1.10

library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib, WordNumber
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
  default-language:    Haskell2010

executable wordnumber
  hs-source-dirs:      app
  main-is:             Main.hs
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  build-depends:       base
                     , WordNumber
  default-language:    Haskell2010

test-suite wordnumber-test
  type:                exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs:      test
  main-is:             Spec.hs
  build-depends:       base
                     , WordNumber
                     , hspec
  ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

**Update**:
Actually I feel a bit stupid for not finding the answer myself. It is either `stack test` or `stack build --test` and also documented.

However, for people following the HaskellBook it might not be that obvious. For some reason all tests in the testing chapter are executed in the cumbersome way and running tests with `stack test` is never mentioned.

Comment: Maybe post your .cabal? You should be able to run just `stack test`

Comment: That's actually exactly what I was after. I didn't know that `stack test` should do what I want. It's working, thanks!

Comment: @Zpalmtree feel free to add an answer, then I can mark it closed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`stack test` runs tests located in a .cabal file. It runs `stack build` if required, so you don't need to build manually before testing.

See further: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#stack-test

Comment: For some reason that I can't understand, _sometimes_ a plain `stack test` won't see the latest modifications made to the spec files. I usually give `stack clean && stack test`, wasting a few seconds of my life budget at each run.